# Уведомление о входе в Компьютер (локальную учетную запись)

Tags: windows, powershell, telegram, smtp, active-directory

Поступила задача от руководителя: он хочет чтобы ему приходило уведомление если кто-то "сел" за его компьютер. Например кто-то из сотрудников сел за его компьютер, набрал пароль, т.е. вошел в систему, руководителю пришло оповещение. Если перевести на более грамотный язык, уведомление об авторизации его учетной записи (AD) с его локального компьютера.
Оповещение по почте, либо через смс или telegram например, я не знаю что будет проще настроить.
Можно ли как-то это настроить и каким способом, подскажите пожалуйста.
Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Что удалось найти, это первая ссылка - Notify My Device, я бы не стал доверять сторонним программам. Следующее это уже из опыта - телефоны на базе андроид изначально очень неплохо экосистематизируюся, в моем случае это был Honor - у них есть свой софт для подобных вещей. Можно получать даже уведомления о попытках входа в почту например. UPD Сделать софт самому. От delphi до c# берем, и ныряем с головой в процесс :)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Собственно, Вы сами и описали пути решения зхадачи своим вопросом. Как подсказывает Владимир Клыков: источник событий журнал событий аудита (по-умолчанию настроенный на фиксацию событий logon). Созданине триггера Планироващика задач выполняется одной строкой: Powershell, либо schtasks.exe. Примеров простых Powershell-скриптов отправки через SMTP-шлюз в открытом доступе достаточно. Если нужно SMS-оповещение, можно воспользоваться услугой SMTP/HTTP-SMS шлюза. Можно установить Telegram-бота. В общем, как определитесь с инструментами, выложите, пожалуйста, скрипты/коды реализаций.

Comment: Вам и правда нужны такие коды или вы из праздного интереса? @Daemon-5

Comment: Мне - не очень, может кому пригодится, как готовая задача.

Answer (score 2):

"Аудит безопасности" так называется ваша хотелка.
А точнее вам нужно смотреть журналы аудита, там есть успешные и неудачные попытки входа. На основании событий можно узнать обо всех входах в систему(в том числе служб и прочего).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]